# How to change decimal separator?

Tags: python, excel, sqlite, pandas

I have an Excel spreadsheet (an extract from SAP). I turn this into a DataFrame, do calculations and save it to an SQLite database. The Excel spreadsheet has comma as decimal separator. The SQLite database uses a dot as decimal separator.

Extract from the code:

```
df_mce3 = pd.read_excel('rawdata/filename.xlsx', header=0, converters={'supplier': str, 'month': str}, decimal=',')
```

`decimal=','` only works with CSV files. I use following code to save the results to an SQLite database:

```
conn = sqlite.connect("database.db")
df_mce3.to_sql("rawdata", conn, if_exists="replace")
df_ka_ext.to_sql("costanalysis_external", conn, if_exists="replace")
[...]
```

Input:

```
month   ordqty  ordprice    ordervolume invoiceqty  invoiceprice    
08.2017 10,000  14,90       149,00      10,000      14,90
```

Output:

```
month   ordqty  ordprice    ordervolume invoiceqty  invoiceprice    
08.2017 10.000  14.90       149.00      10.000      14.90
```

I need those numbers to have the same decimal separator as the input data and I cannot find a way to do this. I am using Python 3.5 with Pandas 0.19.1 and NumPy 1.11.2 on Mac OS X.

Comment: What if you tried: f_mce3[cols[1:]] = df_mc3[cols[1:]].replace('.', ',') ?

Comment: Just tried it without luck. The datatype of those columns containing numbers is "float64" for which there is no .replace(). At least that is what I am told when i try to use your method on a single variable containing a float (number = 1234.45 | number.replace('.', ',') results in an error).

Comment: No issues, this should help: `f_mce3[cols[1:]] = df_mc3[cols[1:]].astype(str).replace('.', ',')`

Comment: It did work only partially. The decimal separator was not changed but rows with 'NaN' got transformed into 'nan'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the `float` values before saving. Just loop through the column with values containing `.`, convert each value to string and then you can use `replace` method.

Here I converted all values in column `x`

```py
df['x'] = [str(val).replace('.', ',') for val in df['x']]
df.to_sql('rawdata', conn, if_exists='replace')
```

Answer (score 0):

After the comments I finally came up with a solution that works at least with sample data. I will have to check if it works with my actual data.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))

def formatnumbers(x):
    x = round(x, 4)
    x = str(x).replace('.', ',')
    return x

for col in df.columns:
    df[col] =  df[col].apply(formatnumbers)

print(df.head(n=5))
```

Result is:

```
         A        B        C        D
0  -0,4065  -1,6113   0,2257   0,7424
1   0,8349   0,0316   -1,105  -1,6463
2  -0,2108   0,7356  -1,0823   0,5261
3   0,3382   0,6158   0,6117  -0,3896
4   -0,403  -1,3639   0,8691   0,5791
```